# What is the most general holomorphic function whose real part is $ u(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy)?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have used the Cauchy Riemann equations $ u_{x}=v_{y}$ to get that $ v_{y}=2xe^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy)-2ye^{x^2-y^2}sin(2xy) $ but I am really unsure how to integrate this. Any hints of identities would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let $e^{z^2}$..

Comment: $ e^{z^2}=e^{x^2-y^2} $ ?@MyGlasses

Comment: No. Is your $u_x$ true?

Comment: what do you mean by true ? @MyGlasses

Comment: Your result for $u_x$ is wrong. Also think about derivating $e^{x^2-y^2} \sin(2 x y)$ with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

It is simpler to write $u(z)=e^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)=e^{x^2-y^2}\,{\bf Re}\,e^{2ixy}={\bf Re}\,e^{x^2-y^2}\,e^{2ixy}={\bf Re}\,e^{z^2}$

Comment: can you please write a detailed answer because I am not sure how this helps

Comment: @aprilsymmetry $f=u+iv={\bf Re}\,f+i{\bf Im}\,f$